Merging vector layers from GML only if |layername= exists
I have a folder with different GML files and some of them have a specific |layername that I need and want to merge with other GML files that also contain that |layername using PyQGIS
I have a folder in a list that appends the specific "|layername=x" to the path so it becomes
RPfolder = ["pathname/folder/gmllayerthatineed1|layername=x","pathname/folder/gmllayerthatineed2|layername=x"]



processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
{ 'CRS' : None, 'LAYERS' : RPfolder , 'OUTPUT' : "path.gml" })

However, because some of the GML files don't have the specific layername in the file I'm getting an error.
Is there a way to check if the file has the specific layername, and only then merge them?

I havent tried it with GML but you probably could use fiona.listlayers() to get the names of all the layers in each GML file?

The classical way to find content in an XML file is to use XPath

fiona.listlayers() worked! Thanks!

Using fiona : fiona.listlayers()
import fiona

RPfolder = ["pathname/folder/gmllayerthatineed1","pathname/folder/gmllayerthatineed2"]
RPfolderName= []
RPlist = []

for path in RPfolder:
    RPlist = fiona.listlayers(path)
    if 'x' in RPlist:
        RPfolderName.append(path + "|layername=x")

processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
{ 'CRS' : None, 'LAYERS' : RPfolderName , 'OUTPUT' : "path.gml" })


worked!
